# I m not able to send Json data to Django views.py , im trying Ajax for this but its not working , also its show CSRF error

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-views, csrf

I'm facing an issue with CSRF verification in a Django project when making an AJAX POST request. Here's a simplified version of my code:

**registration.html ***

```
 <form  method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
(----this revieves the data------)
          {% csrf_token %}

          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />

          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required />

          <label for="password">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required />

          <input type="submit" value="Register"  name="createuser"/>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  
  <script>
    let URLd ="{% url 'defaultpg' %}"
    let  nameInput = document.getElementById("name");
    let  emailInput = document.getElementById("email");
    let  passwordInput = document.getElementById("password");
(------below funtion validates it -----)
    function validateForm() {
      var csrfToken = $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']");

      let nameValue = nameInput.value;
      let emailValue = emailInput.value;
      let passwordValue = passwordInput.value;
      let isNameValid = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(nameValue);
      let isEmailValid = /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/.test(emailValue);
      let isPasswordValid = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,}$/.test(passwordValue);
      if (isNameValid) {
        if (isEmailValid) {
          if (isPasswordValid) {
            alert("Successful");
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '/defaultpg',
              headers: {"X-CSRFToken":'{{ csrf_token }}'},
              data: {
                "name": nameValue,
                "email": emailValue,
                "password": passwordValue,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]")
            },          
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {
                  // any process in data
                  alert("successful");
              },
              error: function () {
                  alert("failure");
              }
          });
          } else {
            alert("Password must contain letters, capital letter, small letter, special character, and numbers with a length above 8");
          }
        } else {
          alert("Please enter a valid Email Address");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Please enter a valid Name");
      }
    }
</script>

view.py
@csrf_protect
def defaultpg(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        print("------------------------")
        print(name)
        print(email)
        print(password)
        print("------------------------")

#I put print statement just to see whether data is received or not 
        return redirect('Entry')

urls .py
    path('eafterhome/', views.defaultpg, name='defaultpg'),
```

I just want that the data shall be received by view.defaultpg ,Im new to django i m doing this for my final yr project a little help would be nice

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<form  method="POST" id="someForm">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required />

    <input type="submit" value="Register"  name="createuser"/>
</form>

  <script>
    const someForm = document.getElementById("someForm")

    someForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault() // prevent default behavior of the form

        var csrfToken = $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val();
        
        // rest of your logic goes here....
    })

</script>
```

Also note: if you send the json data to django view.. you can handle incoming data like this:

```
def defaultpg(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        import json
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        name = data.get("name")
        email = data.get('email')
        password = data.get('password')
```

Comment: so shall I put the whole function in it

Comment: @AryanBagwe yep.

Comment: its showing csrf error

Comment: @AryanBagwe letme see your Ajax request code also the more details about the error.